# How to access application data in a session .jsp file

Tags: java, html, jsp, session

I am executing the following loop to view all my session attributes:

```
<%
  for (Enumeration e = session.getAttributeNames(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {     
      String attribName = (String) e.nextElement();
      Object attribValue = session.getAttribute(attribName);
%>
<BR>
<%= attribName %> - <%= attribValue %>
```

Which will output:

```
user.principal.key / user.ip.address.key / session.user.key
```

However, I wish to access more of the user information that might not exist in session yet, like other variables I set in the user.java file.

How would be the best way to store these variables in the session, so I may go about printing them to my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set them as a session attributes:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("myVariable", variableValue);
}
```

Use some tag library like `JSTL` to access attributes sent from servlet instead of using scriptlets.
In case of `JSTL` use `out` to print value of your variable:

```
<c:out value="${myVariable}" />
```

Don't forget to include `JSTL` tag lib in your `JSP`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and to download `JSTL` dependency from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2)

Comment: So I am setting this in my jsp page or my java file?

Comment: `doGet` of course goes to java file (Servlet class). `<c:out value="${myVariable}" />` goes to JSP.

Comment: Right dumb question, is the response entirely necessary however?

Comment: Well, I seem to have a method in a databaseservices class that already takes request, and has the user variables I was looking to add to the session, so I was going to just instantiate the HttpSession session in that class, without using the ServletResponse